# How to make a camera go to a location in Unity (c#)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to make a camera go to an object when right click is held however it's not working how do I fix this? When the button right click is pressed it prints hi and hello however the camera does not move.

Edit: The line "transform.localPosition = MagicWandReg1Pos;" and "   transform.localPosition = CameraReg1Pos;" is what i think is the problem but i just don't know how to fix it.

Edit 2: the problem is the addon cinemachine (i think ) I'm currently working on fixing it).

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class Camscript : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public Vector3 MagicWandReg1Pos;
     public Vector3 CameraReg1Pos;
     
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
         MagicWandReg1Pos = new Vector3(0.9525713f,2,2400557f);
         CameraReg1Pos = new Vector3(-5.601483f,3,150208);
         transform.localPosition = CameraReg1Pos;
     }
 
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
       
         
           if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
           {
     transform.localPosition = MagicWandReg1Pos;
 print("Hello");
           }
 if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse1))
           {
     transform.localPosition = CameraReg1Pos;
     print("Hi");
           }
          
     }
 }
```

Comment: The script is attached to the game object with the Camera on it, right? I'd update your description to say what you mean by "not working"? Is anything moving at all? Should the camera immediately move there like a teleport, or should it smoothly travel over time (short) from the previous location to the new one? Why are you using localPosition instead of position? Local position moves relative to the parent object and regular position refers to world space.

Comment: 1.  Yes, the script is attached to the game object with the camera.                                                                                                                                            
 2. I did I said, "When the button right click is pressed it prints hi and hello however the camera does not move."                                                                                             3. it's supposed to instantly go to the position that I want it to go to.

Comment: 4. (it was too long so I have to use multiple messages)  Yes I know local position refers to parented objects and that was my intent. 5. I forgot to say it's a problem with cinemachine, not my code I forgot to add that when I found out (i found it a couple days ago but no one responded on this site so I thought this post got buried and i would not need to)